# Different results when using IQueryable and IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I notice different comparison results on DateTime type when using IEnumerable and IQueryable.

```
var messages = _dbContext.Messages.ToList();
var test = messages.Any(m => m.CreatedOn == message.CreatedOn); // true - correct
var messages1 = _dbContext.Messages;
var test1 = messages1.Any(m => m.CreatedOn == message.CreatedOn); // false - not correct
```

My model has following transformation:

```
public DateTime CreatedOn { get => _createdOn.ToLocalTime(); set => _createdOn = value.ToUniversalTime(); }
```

I'm comparing DateTime type. Results from db,  when looking up debugger results (one of m.CreatedOn entities) are identical in both cases (same type/value/kind/ticks etc). So, message.CreatedOn should match. And matches when querying IEnumerable, but not when querying IQueryable. What could be explanation of this?

Is it, that IQueryable runs on db SQL query? Then it can't match message.CreatedOn - in my case.

What is missleading, is that lookup in VS degugger shows same results from both interfaces. It must be, thet debugger uses transformation defined in model. Am I right?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This clearly demonstrates how tricky it can be to have [properties with side effects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/82377/37193). Of course, setting a property is a side-effect, but in a narrower sense it means: doing more than is expected. I.e. violating the *principle of least surprise*.

In your case it causes the two flavors of LINQ —to objects, and translated as SQL— to behave differently. EF is "suprised" by the transformation and doesn't deal with it. The key is to share the secret with EF, by a [value conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions).

I have a simple, boring class with two properties, of which both `DateTime` properties map to `DateTime(2)` columns in Sql Server:

```cs
class Class1
{
    DateTime _value;
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Value
    { 
        get => _value.ToLocalTime(); 
        set => _value = value.ToUniversalTime();
    }
    public DateTime ConvValue { get ; set ; }
}
```

I want `ConvValue` to display local time, just as `Value`, but now with EF in the loop. So I add this configuration:

```cs
class Class1Config : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Class1>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Class1> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(c => c.ConvValue)
            .HasConversion(v => v.ToUniversalTime(), v => v.ToLocalTime());
                                // ^^ to database            ^^ from database
    }
}
```

Then I add this content to the database (notice the milliseconds, and the `00` hours):

| ID | Value | ConvValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 00:01:01.0010000 | 2020-01-01 00:01:01.0010000 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 00:01:01.0020000 | 2020-01-01 00:01:01.0020000 |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 00:01:01.0030000 | 2020-01-01 00:01:01.0030000 |

I get your issue (reversed) by executing these queries (in Linqpad):

```cs
DateTime refd;
using (var db = getContext())
{
    refd = db.Classes.First().Value;
}
using (var db = getContext())
{
    db.Classes.Count(c => c.Value == refd).Dump();                 // 0
    db.Classes.AsEnumerable().Count(c => c.Value == refd).Dump();  // 1
}
```

The 0 is because first `Count` query runs this SQL code in my time zone:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Classes] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[Value] = @__refd_0',N'@__refd_0 datetime2(7)',
    @__refd_0='2020-01-01 01:01:01.0010000'
```

As you see, the parameter is in my local time (+ 1h), because that's how the first query produced it (`refd` is `2020-01-01 01:01:01.001`). EF straightforwardly translates the query from the model information it's got.

The same queries based on `ConvValue` give expected results:

```cs
db.Classes.Count(c => c.ConvValue == refd).Dump();                 // 1
db.Classes.AsEnumerable().Count(c => c.ConvValue == refd).Dump();  // 1
```

Now EF knows about the conversion and transforms the parameter to UTC before translating it into SQL (`00` hours):

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Classes] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[ConvValue] = @__refd_0',N'@__refd_0 datetime2(7)',
    @__refd_0='2020-01-01 00:01:01.0010000'
```

Comment: BTW, not that I'm a fan of this transformation. I'd rather have an unmapped getter-only property like `LocalValue`, or do the transformation in a view model, and by convention only set UTC values. It's easy to make mistakes with `DateTime` transformations.

Answer (score -1):

When you use `.ToList()` your query is executed on the database, so the `.Any(...)` that follows will just check the properties that are already loaded in memory.

In your second example the `.Any(...)` is extending the IQueryable and will also be translated into the SQL that is sent to the database, and the database will actually do the `CreatedOn` comparison based on column data.

You could always use the SQL Server Profiler (included in SSMS) to capture the actual queries that are coming in at the database, it often gives some extra insight.

Btw, it's likely that the database has a different level of precision for a datetime field  than C# and therefore yields different results.